# Assignment of undefined to declared but uninitialized variables?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

Is there any particular reason why the following occurs?

```
var newVar;
newVar; //returns "undefined"
```

It gets really confusing when:

```
newVar == undefined; //true
newVar == null; //true
```

I've read some threads that suggest using the typeof operator instead to detect if a variable is declared but initialized and to always initialize a declared variable with null, however:

```
typeof newVar //returns object
```

While I'm aware that (correct me if I'm wrong) `null` is an object placeholder and is thus an object type, the way this is handled in JavaScript is just really confusing for me.

Professional JS for Web Developers says:
[image: null == undefined]

In what way is `null` a derivative of `undefined`?

Sorry for the pepperage of questions - but thanks in advance to all answers.

Comment: I have great respect for Mr Zakas but I don't think that `undefined` is in any way a "derivative" of `null`. I'm not even sure what that means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation ship between `undefined` and `null` can be confusing, hopefully this clears it up:

First of all, they are values [two different data types](http://es5.github.io/#x8):

> The Undefined type has exactly one value, called `undefined`. Any variable that has not been assigned a value has the value `undefined`.

(which also explains why the variable has the value `undefined` at first) and

> The Null type has exactly one value, called `null`.

The makes more sense if you use strict comparison:

```
null === undefined // false
```

So why does `null == undefined` result in `true`? [Because the specification says so](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3):

> 2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
>
> 3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.

So,

> In what way is `null` a derivative of `undefined`?

It isn't. They are two different values of two different data types. Maybe conceptually, it is some kind of "derivative", but not from a technical point of view. The book is either over-simplifying or over-complicating it in this point.

---

> While I'm aware that (correct me if I'm wrong) null is an object placeholder and is thus an object type, the way this is handled in JavaScript is just really confusing for me.

`typeof null` returns `'object'`, [because the specification says so](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3). It's confusing because the data type of `null` [is in actually Null](http://es5.github.io/#x8.2), not Object (as explained at the very top). You are right, maybe the original purpose for `null` was to represent the absence of an object, but in fact, it can be used to represent the absence of *any* value.